# Work responsibilities after service contract was expired

Tags: contracts

I have been working for a software company for one year. On July 15th, my contract expired and I found a new promising job. However I still agreed to stay at the former company for one month under a service contract (which means I get paid for every day I come to work). We also agreed that I will stop working under the service contract on August 15th.

However, I was sick on August 15th (the last day of service contract), which made my project 20% unfinished (based on the number of "tickets", I have 3/15 tickets unfinished). By the way, during that time, I have finished transferring my know-hows to other colleagues as well.

Should I come back and finish the rest, guys? And if so, should I do it for one day (to compensate for the other sick leave) or until the job is finished?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know contract law and IANAL, but the first thing I wonder is, were you paid for that day? If so, are you/were you authorized paid time off? If not, then you owe the company compensation in return, either a day's work or the value of the day's pay, right? By asking this you seem to be asking about the ethical vs the contract. I would determine what is _required_ (by law), and only then what is _right_. They may (or may not) be the same thing.

Comment: No I haven't get paid yet. I think I will not get paid for that day

Comment: Why not just ask the company what they'd prefer? If you're not in a dispute there's no real reason to delve into what each parties responsibilities are in this situation.

Answer (score 4):

> Should I come back and finish the rest, guys? And if so, should I do
>   it for one day (to compensate for the other sick leave) or until the
>   job is finished?

You need to ask the company what they would prefer you do, since they are paying you for your work.

If it were me, I'd offer to work at least one more day.

I'd also offer to work to complete the job, assuming it didn't interfere with my new, promising job.